# Invalid_token_response An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: 404 not found

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, oauth-2.0, keycloak

When I try to authenticate to my app running on /myclient with keycloak, this message is shown to me:

[invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: 404 not found
[image]

The url on login page looks correct:

```
https://somedomain.com/keycloakt1/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=myclient&scope=openid&state=DoA9p8UZDdTmWSldH4iL-R1NESKN13IUbzdSw5qbtsE%3D&redirect_uri=https://somedomain/myclient/login/oauth2/code/keycloak&nonce=-KmNNXpETgea6mgDXubuBxXG9pLxVjssWTYQ6xmfifA
```

Request from postman to get token is successful on url `https://somedomain.com/keycloakt1/realms/myclient/protocol/openid-connect/token`

I have keycloak running on context /keycloakt1.

I provided this configuration to my application.yaml

```
 spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri: 'https://somedomain.com/keycloakt1/realms/myrealm'
 spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id: myclient
 spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri: 'https://somedomain.com/keycloakt1/realms/myrealm'
```

Client config in keycloak:

[image]

[image]

I have another environment where keycloak is running on https://keycloak.test.com/ without context and on this env login to the same app with same configuration is working without issue.

Can anybody help?

**UPDATE**

When I list the well knows endpoints from /.well-known/openid-configuration

I see some endpoints is missing the /keycloakt1/ in the uri especially the token_endpoint which probably causing the error. Can anybody know how to resolve this?

```
"issuer": "https://somedomain/keycloakt1/realms/myclient",
"authorization_endpoint": "https://somedomain/keycloakt1/realms/myclient/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
-----> THERE IS MISSING /keycloakt1/ "token_endpoint": "https://somedomain/realms/myclient/protocol/openid-connect/token",
-----> THERE IS MISSING /keycloakt1/ "introspection_endpoint": "https://somedomain/realms/myclient/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect",
-----> THERE IS MISSING /keycloakt1/ "userinfo_endpoint": "https://somedomain/realms/myclient/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
"end_session_endpoint": "https://somedomain/keycloakt1/realms/myclient/protocol/openid-connect/logout",
"frontchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
"frontchannel_logout_supported": true,
-----> THERE IS MISSING /keycloakt1/ "jwks_uri": "https://somedomain/realms/myclient/protocol/openid-connect/certs",
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to retrieve the token from `https://somedomain.com/keycloakt1/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=myclient&scope=openid&state=DoA9p8UZDdTmWSldH4iL-R1NESKN13IUbzdSw5qbtsE%3D&redirect_uri=https://somedomain/myclient/login/oauth2/code/keycloak&nonce=-KmNNXpETgea6mgDXubuBxXG9pLxVjssWTYQ6xmfifA` while it out be (as correctly in your Postman) `https://somedomain.com/keycloakt1/realms/myclient/protocol/openid-connect/token`.

Maybe a misconfiguration in your application?

Update: Take a look at the [Keycloak documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/server/hostname). I think you didnt configure the hostname.

Comment: The first url is generated by the app and the format looks ok. On my other environment where its working, the url differ in keycloak domain where its running without context on  https://keycloak.test.com/

Comment: Show us all URLs and we can help you. Update your question please.

Comment: Just edited. Please take a look.